# Why does the alt+enter combination only work sometimes in org mode?

Tags: org-mode

I used to be able to use alt+enter to create new entries in org mode. EMACS suddenly stopped responding to the combination and started to return "M-kp-enter is undefined". How can I get it to work again?

Many thanks.

PS I'm using EMACS on Windows 8.

Comment: Take this with a grain of salt, but I think that Org binds this behavior to `M-return` rather than `M-kp-enter` in `local-function-key-map`. This means that either Windows sends the key code Org doesn't expect to receive, or that the keyboard sends an incorrect key code in this combination. If you feel adventurous you could modify the mentioned keymap to have `M-kp-enter` map to the same thing as `M-return` and see if that works (it'd be best to tell Org developers if it does, they'd like to look into that too).

Comment: Are you pressing Alt+Enter or Alt+KP_Enter (i.e. are you using the Enter key on the main part of the keyboard or on the keypad)? If you're using the keypad, did it always work with the keypad? Which version of Emacs are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'm using EMACS on a laptop which doesn't have a keypad. The key combination used to work just fine (on the same machine) just a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: wvxvw I'm not a programmer and I don't have the slightest idea how to modify the settings' files you mention.

Comment: You could try something like this: `M-: (add-to-list 'local-function-key-map (cons 'M-kp-enter (cdr (assoc 'M-return local-function-key-map))))` and hopefully nothing will explode :)

Comment: Have you turned `numlock` on somehow? That might cause enter to be interpreted as kp_enter (i.e. enter on the numpad), if your numpad is overlayed on the standard keyboard?

Comment: just my grain of salt too. I would, like Gilles, think of keypad. But you say you have no keypad. So I would think of your return key beeing modified in some way : what about your cap locks ? or, in windows 8, some key combination change the language of the keyboard (I don't remember which, may be Left Alt + Shift), and this is a key combination you may use in emacs, that Windows 8 undestands for himself.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but it suddenly happened to me too.

squidly had the correct answer but his reply was hidden so I had to work it out for myself.

I had accidentally pressed 'NumLock' (top-right-hand-corner, 4-keys to the left on my keyboard). I hadn't realised for at least a year that there are two 'Enter' keys on my keyboard and Emacs thinks they are different.